# How do I store session data on a local HTML site?

Tags: javascript, html, session

How do I store session data between page views on a local (i.e. file://) website?

I'm trying to implement a login mechanism for a web site using JavaScript that is to be burned to a disc and run from there.

This precludes the usage of a web server, and thus, HTTP. This means that cookies are not feasible.

It appears that while Firefox and IE supports cookies on local HTML pages, Chrome and Safari do not - not surprising, given that cookies are a HTTP construct, not HTML.

Storing data on a file isn't possible, due to the JavaScript sandbox while running within the browsers.

HTML5 localstorage/sessionstorage isn't ideal, if only because of the fact that I'm unsure of the environment it will be running in and if it supports HTML5.

So basically, how do I track if a user is logged in on a local page without HTTP on HTML4?

Comment: You might want to look at [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/).  There is no completely cross-browser, cross-OS way to do what you want, unfortunately.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the "session" once you have it? In all likelihood the most compatible, easiest to implement solution would be to use query string parameters to persist data between between your pages.

Comment: Also it's kind-of hard to imagine what the point is of requiring a login to an "application" that consists of nothing but HTML in local files, which can trivially be compromised by a quick trip through a text editor.

Comment: @Pointy It's all in the requirements! ;) It's a web-design assignment, and having actual login functionality is a nice-to-have. Security isn't too high a priority in this case, especially given the circumstances.

Comment: @DavidBrainer-Banker That is a pretty good idea, actually, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any other options, maybe an encrypted querystring parameter that gets passed around? If it's not in the querystring, then assume user is logged out. All pages that rely on a logged-in user will have to decrypt the value and validate each time before loading.

Comment: Pretty good workaround the whole issue which I hadn't thought about. Ten points to Gryffindor!

Answer (score 1):

Can you use Flash?

If you can, you might have luck with Flash Cookies:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object

Answer (score 0):

Another idea I just had:

Once the user has logged in, build a frameset in which you embed the actual content files.
That way the user never leaves the page and you can store all data you want in a hidden or small frame.